# how to solve css validation using Total Validator tool in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, css

To solve the errors I have to modify `calendar.css` and `styles-m.css`. What are the proper way of customizing theses css files in my custom theme.

These are the file paths where I want to modify.

1. `static/frontend/DGX/Luma/en_US/mage/calendar.css`
2. `static/frontend/DGX/Luma/en_US/css/styles-m.css`
3. `static/frontend/DGX/Luma/en_US/css/styles-l.css`
4. `static/frontend/DGX/Luma/en_US/css/print.css`

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

don't look in pub/static folder its not good practice. if you need to change any css property please follow below instruction.

first you need to create your custom theme [refer this link](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html)

for examle:

To override app/design/frontend/Magento/blank/web/css/source/_theme.less

Copy the file **app/design/frontend/Magento/blank/web/css/source/_theme.less** to the folder **`app/design/frontend/<Vendor>/<Theme Name>/web/css/source/_theme.less`**

then make changes, clear the cache of magento and browser. you could able to see the changes.

**similarly you can done for CSS**

in case you need any clarification just mention in comment

[refer this for css change](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css-overview.html)

Comment: Yes,I did the same .But for calendar.css  I don't understand where I have to copy the file.Because it is located at magento/lib/web/mage/calendar.css,outside of the theme directory.