# Less Compilation in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, theme, less-css

I`m trying to make a new theme and all steps are done:

- Create theme directory `app/design/frontend/MySite/MyTheme`
- Create `theme.xml` file under `app/design/frontend/MySite/MyTheme`
- Add `registration.php`

And I found my theme in my admin panel , Now I overriding `_theme.less` file. but how the less will be compile? I'm using localhost (xammp)

I had to delete files inside these directories manually after finishing my edit but no result: `pub/static/frontend/YourVendorName/YourTheme/`, `var/cache/` and `var/view_preprocessed`

Comment: I hope this link helps you http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/111446/how-to-solve-css-validation-using-total-validator-tool-in-magento-2/111451#111451

Comment: none of both questions have a good answer :(

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism i will try it , thanks

Comment: I hope this link helps [click here](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/95420/how-to-update-customize-override-magento-2-css-styles/143973#143973)

Answer (score 1):

As you haven't mentioned client-side I presume you are currently compiling LESS with server-side compilation enabled?

To compile on server-side mode I recommend clearing pub/static and var/view_preprocessed then navigating to the Magento root directory and running `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

If you don't wish to do this all the time I recommend changing to client-side compilation. To do this login to the admin and go to `stores > config > advanced > developer > Front-end development workflow` and changing it to client-side. This will then compile the less on each page refresh, although there are times I still need to clear pub/static.

If that doesn't work I would double check your code/file structure and as a last resort disable varnish and your caches.

Comment: all this stuff is already done , i trying one with the server-side compilation and other time client-side compilation ... in all cases and on my experience the client side is boring and really slow  , the server side is also boring because you need to deploy every time you add a single line in the less .. Magento going to make me a crazy :(

Comment: If client-side is working correctly then client-side should load within a second or two. A third option, you can use grunt - http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css_debug.html

Comment: how i deploy my theme only ?? the "php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy" deploy all themes and its take so long time ?

Comment: i found in my deploy that i have 10 errors :( how to know them ?

Comment: There's currently no way to only deploy 1  theme :( I have asked about the errors but no one has answered - http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/112442/magento-2-how-to-view-static-content-deploy-errors

Comment: Thanks man .. final question i changed the client side method and also remove all the files under  pub/static . the rules in the _theme only work in the first time ... after that its cant deploy the static folder again why ?

Comment: My experience with client-side is that you don't need to clear the pub/static folder unless you're adding new files. You can just clear the one module from pub/static you don't need to clear them all. So after you've cleared pub/static it doesn't regenerate them?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38948/discussion-between-mohamed-samy-and-ben-space-48).

Comment: i clear this path pub/static/frontend/<Vendor>/<theme>/
and change my _theme , an refreshed the page and its look that no have any css file ?

Comment: I've replied in chat, in short it's likely to be due to errors in your LESS.